# "Deployment Target Options" absent in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to customize the visual studio emulator for android studio like this:

[image: the pic in the how-to]
<sub>Linked from https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.</sub>

But I have not an option "Deployment Target Options":
[image: the pic in my try]

Please help me somebody!

Comment: android studio 3.5

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Comment: I've filed a report about this issue to google, you can make your case in here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144249612 maybe google will listen.

Answer (score 0):

Available deployment targets are present in **navigation bar** in android studio 3.5

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it's not the same, if I unplug my phone the target jumps to something else which is very annoying. If I'm not careful enough Android Studio will start a virtual machine without me asking it.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio go to: run -> select device, follow the instructions there.